# javascript - every method doesn't stop once predicate returns falsy

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what `every` method really does in Javascript.

I have a following block code:

```
const data = null;
const arr = [
  data,
  data.name
];

const outcome = arr.every(Boolean);
console.log(outcome); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I thought it would return `false` because the first item in array is a `falsy` value, however it throws an Error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

The document of [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) says:

> The `every` method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callback returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, the `every` method immediately returns false.

So I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs when you define `arr`, not in `every`. `data` is `null`, so `data.name` is invalid, and that's why you get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error message.